# Notepad++ Syntax Highlighting: Collapse indented

Tags: notepad++

I am creating a ChoiceScript (https://github.com/dfabulich/choicescript) syntax highlighting file in Notepad++. ChoiceScript is a scripting language for creating interactive fiction. Its most important tags are the *choice tag (used to denote a choice the user can make) and # (used to denote the text of that choice).
I'd like the ability to collapse all lines beneath a line that begins with *choice or # that are indentet farther than their parent. For example, in

```
How are you?
*choice
  #Good
    Glad to hear it.
  #Bad
    I'm sorry to hear it.
```

I'd like the entire block beneath *choice to be collapsible, as well as the answers beneath #Good and #Bad. How can I do this?

Comment: I think this isn't possible in N++. You can have custom folding (see `Language > Define your language`) but I think a close tag is needed, and there's no option taking into account the indentation.

Comment: Hi psxls, thanks for your reply! I know the custom highlighting dialog, I was hoping there was some trick to get it to work with indenting. Collapsing indents i definitely possible, it works with the built-in python highlighting. It may be neccessary to edit the xml highlighting files, but they're pretty much over my head.

Comment: @psxls It seem to be possible if you set your language to Python. How is that done? It should be possible to replicate it to a custom language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251858/hide-comments-in-notepad Duplicate (2010 is the earliest I could find).

Answer (score -1):

Do the following thing  Language > Define your language > folding in code 1 style

Put * # and save it .hope fully it works.