# Custom regions for code folding in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, custom-component, folding

Is there any way to create custom named regions for Notepad++ to fold them?

I've seen some talk about it but found no functional example of how to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notepad++ user defined regions with folding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251858/hide-comments-in-notepad Duplicate (2010 is the earliest I could find).

Answer (score 5):

I use:

```
//{ NAME OF REGION/BLOCK

//}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that everything you need to know is described here:

http://udl20.weebly.com/folding-in-code.html

it's official documentation, you can find link to it in custom language editor:

"Language\Define your language ..."