# How do you get Notepad++ to treat # (hashtag) like a comment?

Tags: sql, configuration, notepad++, tweak

I have an SQL export file from my server with comments. The line comment operator used was the hashtag `#`. Notepad++ does not treat this like a commented out line, as in, the color does not change and any words such as `like` and `while` are changed to bold blue.

When you run the script on the server to install the SQL, it runs fine, the comments are treated as they should be. How do you tell NPP that the # operator is supposed to comment out the line? **Both show the color and have `Ctrl-k` add a `#` in front of the line.**

*Note: I added `commentLine="#"` in the langs.xml file with no luck.*

Comment: I have written my own SQL "User-Defined Language", as suggested by @konstantin-jäger. It works for the most part, does what I need it to do (Including the `Ctrl+K` option) so that is what I am using for now. I have a XML script if anyone wants one, but I am not going to accept this as a solution because it isn't what I was looking for (or anyone else who comes across this in the future) because I was wanting to slightly tweak an existing language rather then write my own because writing your own will never be in a NPP update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251858/hide-comments-in-notepad Duplicate (2010 is the earliest I could find).

Answer (score 0):

View -> User defined Dialogue -> Comment & number -> Comment Line

There you type in "#"

Before this you need to define a new language in the upper buttons.

What means, that the whole rest of the syntax isn't highlighted anymore.
But you could define it that way, how you want to. So you have an individual Syntax Highlighting including the commenting via "#"

Comment: This requires the rewriting of an entire language file, SQL, then just add the # line. Is there any way to just add this one operator? If I could copy the current SQL code from somewhere then this MIGHT be an option. But I am sure there is an easier way to add a single operator to a language rather then uninstalling that language and rewriting it.

Comment: That might be an idea. Since the xml of an own defined language is defined in the same way, you could try to copy the most of it, and paste it into your defined xml. They are stored in the NPP folder in your system under plugins -> temp. Your language will be stored in plugins->APIs. Try to play with it. It could be that you have to set up the colors. I don't know if they are defined there, too. (But I think they are).

Comment: Or you could create an own language, add # as comment line and check it's xml for the correct code. Maybe you made an error? In that way the code is written by NPP and it should be correct. Maybe the pasting of the correct code line will allow the # as a comment in the preset SQL-language file.

Comment: Well, it turns out that just writing my own user language is not going to work, I don't know enough about SQL to know all the possible operators (,<!@'`"$% etc or if you can prepend a word with a character to make it variable or whatever. I can't seem to find anything more than a keyword list for SQL. I am sorry to say that this option will not work...