# Notepad++ region highlighing

Tags: notepad++, highlighting, region

Is there a way to assign specific color to ranges of lines in my code?  The basic functionality I want: assign a different colors to different ranges of line numbers so that I can easily scroll down to find the color region I need.

Even better functionality would include automatic distinct coloring based on function definition.  Also, a side bar similar to what WinMerge has which displays fast access to the different lines of code would be excellent.

I am using notepad++ to write in Javascript if that makes a different (probably shouldn't though).

I have read [notepad++ user defined regions with folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding) which seems like it has some color options, but I do not see User-Defined Dialogue when I click the view tab.

If this feature is not supported and there are no external plugins which allow this (I don't know the extent of how much you can alter the program using plugins), how difficult would it be to write this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight a block of code in Notepad++, please do the following steps

1. Select the required text.
2. Right click to display the context menu
3. Choose `Style token` and select any of the five choices available ( styles from `Using 1st style`  to `using 5th style`). Each is of different colors.If you want yellow color choose `using 3rd style`.

If you want to create your own style you can use `Style Configurator` under `Settings` menu.