# Custom Code Folding - code folding wherever I want (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, folding

I am majoring in financial studies and write my R code primarily in Notepad++.

I also use Notepad++ to write my thoughts and plans before moving the final version to Latex.

What I wanted to do is to **use Notepad++ to be able to fold wherever I want, on whatever language I write**, whether it is Python, R, etc., even plain txt too.

vim/emacs may or may not have that feature already, but I don't think I have the willingness to study one of them since the learning curve is steep

I hope that there's a specific way to do the custom folding so as not to interfere with the native code-folding feature of Notepad++ (ex: like how `#` trigger comment in R, or like in Python).

Comment: Not a complete solution, but a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding

Comment: @Firhat : What kind of elements would you use to define the beginning and end of the blocks you want to fold?

Comment: the way i want it, the identifier should be is a customizable so i can make a #, or $ or a tab or a // or a vertical space to trigger the folding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely go with User-Defined styles for the text files.

For Ruby, since it is an already defined language, you can either

- Try to redefine the language as a user-one + add your additional folding items (but it is very painful)
- Use a work-around as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472818/1603480

But, that would be for a specific language so you would have to select the style for each language (so doesn't meet your requirement "for any language").

Probably a solution would be a macro or a Python script modifying your text (for example by using the hide function of Notepad++).