# Notepad++ Where's the User Defined Dialogue?

Tags: notepad++, levels

I've been trying to have custom defined levels so I can collapse big sections of code, but I can't find the User Defined Dialogue option in the View menu.

Is there another way to collapse User Defined code?

Comment: Check this if this helps:- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=User_Defined_Languages

Comment: I want to ADD on to the language I'm using currently, not create a new one :/

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3761206/2140859

Comment: No, I mean, the option, "User Defined Dialogue", isn't in the View drop down menu. Literally.

Answer (score 1):

The View / User Defined Dialogue selection disappeared for me as well when I upgraded from v6.1.3 to v6.5.5, but I found in the documentation below (they seem to be switching to the terminology UDL, or User Defined Languages), that there is an icon on the toolbar that takes you to the User Defined Dialogue screen

C:\Program Files\Notepad++\user.manual\documentation\notepad-user-manual\languages\user-defined-languages.html