# How to specifically minimized chosen code in html with notepad ++

Tags: html, notepad++, minimize

I want to do is to `minimized` those specific lines in my html codes in my page in order for me to work  without being confuse where to find that specific code. For example:

[image]

Comment: And what is your question? Have you tried to click on the symbol you discribe?

Comment: @M42 yea but it minimize too the html code that i didnt want to minimize

Comment: @M42 my problem is i cant minimize just the part of code that i need

Comment: The word you are looking for is line folding. (to help search). You may need to "Define your own Language". [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding) has some interesting answers: . See also: [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/626194/how-to-use-codefolding-feature-of-notepad-for-normal-text-documents) on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Select al the lines you want to minimize
2. Right click over the text/lines selected
3. choose the last option of the contextual menu "**hide lines**"
   [image]

This will hide all the lines selected