# Looking for a format to improve my logs

Tags: logging, format

I have logs which are huge plain text file. In this log each line represent a message logged at a specific time, some message represent the beginning of a process, some other represent the end of the same processes.

thus I could have a log which looks like this.

```
<lot of lines>
26-01-2016 10:00:00 - START PROCESS XYZ
<lot of lines>
26-01-2016 11:00:00 - END PROCESS XYZ
<lot of lines>
```

I would like to be able to use a tool which would allow me to expand/collapse what's between "26-01-2016 10:00:00 - START PROCESS XYZ" and "26-01-2016 11:00:00 - END PROCESS XYZ". Of course that tool could rely on a specific format other than the current one.

I bet this pair <format, tool> already exist (maybe even in a lot of different flavours).

Can you suggest me about some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just use {}

Enclose the `<lot of lines>` part in brackets like these `{ }`, and editors like notepad++ will allow you to fold up the section enclosed if you set the language of the file to a programming language.

See this picture to set a language in notepad++
https://malalanayake.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/notepad.png

### Even better:

You can code-fold by a user-defined keyword,
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767593/5054380)