# Notepad++ text tree view

Tags: treeview, notepad++

Is it possible, with or without a plugin in notepad++, to obtain a text tree view of a category within the text? Like the picture below, but like a list within the text?

[image: Like this]

This is basically so I can be able to click the little button that appear to **expand** or **collapse** sections.

Comment: You mean... like this ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/chzid.png

Comment: Alright then. But which one ? I mean, I only use this. I don't know any other (Online text editor like Google Docs don't count)

Comment: wait... do you mean something like @hugo showed?

Comment: Yes, hugo. Exactly like this. But without "coding". Just to make a basic list of thing. Like a category, so I can organize myself.

@Axium I just tried the tab key. It only advance char, but does not do the "thing" like hugo mentionned https://imgur.com/uHyck1D

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding

Comment: @Axium well done! I was gonna suggest to write his list in JSON or XML xD

Comment: Amazing ! It worked ! Thanks. Now, how do I put it as an answer ? I'm new to this site :/

Comment: i can put it as an answer here if you want

Comment: Thanks. But, well, I guess I already did it under. But apparently, I'll only be able to accept my own answer in 2 days. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767593/11914955) was given by @Axium. Thanks to him !

[Click here to read the answer !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767593/11914955)
For short, it use the `Define your language...` tool under `Language` to create your own keyword, defining an open & close bracket when used inside your text. This allow the use of the `Collapse` and `Expand` button at the leftmost menu of Notepad++ program.